# Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Divide by zero error encountered

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    select iif(grouping(T.iNum_Dia) = 1, 32, T.iNum_Dia) NumDia
, iif(grouping(T.iNum_Dia) = 1, 'Totales', max(cast(T.iNum_Dia as varchar) + ' ' + T.cNom_Mes3L)) "DATE"
, iif(grouping(T.iNum_Dia) = 1, '', max(T.cNom_DiaSemana3L_Ing)) "DAY WEEK"
, count(*) Cycles
--, sum(iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) Distancia
, sum(iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) / count(*) "ST Length"
, sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) ASK
, sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) RPK
, sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp) "SEATS AV"
, sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp) / count(*) GAUGE
, sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue) "REVENUE PAX"
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) "PAX REVENUE TOT"
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) * 100 / sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) YIELD
, (sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev))) * 100 / 
  (sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev))) LF
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) * 100 / (sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev))) PRASK
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) / sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue) "AVERAGE FARE"
, sum(S.iInd_MinBlock_Prog) / 60.0 "Block Hours"
, sum(S.iInd_MinVuelo_PV) / 60.0 "Flight Hours"
from DWH_VW.Volados.SumVolado_Leg S
inner join DWH_VW.dbo.DimTiempo T on S.dFec_Vuelo_Real = T.fFecha
inner join DWH_VW.Volados.FactVuelos F on S.iID_Vuelo = F.iID_Vuelo
inner join DWH_VW.Volados.DimRutaOW R on F.iID_RutaOW = R.iID_RutaOW
where datepart(year, S.dFec_Vuelo_Real) = 2020
  and datepart(month, S.dFec_Vuelo_Real) = 8
group by T.iNum_Dia with rollup
order by 1
```

Que me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si trato de agregar la columna ***r.cCod_RutaOW*** de la siguiente manera:

```
select iif(grouping(T.iNum_Dia) = 1, 32, T.iNum_Dia) NumDia
, r.cCod_RutaOW
, iif(grouping(T.iNum_Dia) = 1, 'Totales', max(cast(T.iNum_Dia as varchar) + ' ' + T.cNom_Mes3L)) "DATE"
, iif(grouping(T.iNum_Dia) = 1, '', max(T.cNom_DiaSemana3L_Ing)) "DAY WEEK"
, count(*) Cycles
--, sum(iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) Distancia
, sum(iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) / count(*) "ST Length"
, sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) ASK
, sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) RPK
, sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp) "SEATS AV"
, sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp) / count(*) GAUGE
, sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue) "REVENUE PAX"
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) "PAX REVENUE TOT"
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) * 100 / sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) YIELD
, (sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev))) * 100 / 
  (sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev))) LF
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) * 100 / (sum(S.iInd_Asientos_Disp * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev))) PRASK
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) / sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue) "AVERAGE FARE"
, sum(S.iInd_MinBlock_Prog) / 60.0 "Block Hours"
, sum(S.iInd_MinVuelo_PV) / 60.0 "Flight Hours"
from DWH_VW.Volados.SumVolado_Leg S
inner join DWH_VW.dbo.DimTiempo T on S.dFec_Vuelo_Real = T.fFecha
inner join DWH_VW.Volados.FactVuelos F on S.iID_Vuelo = F.iID_Vuelo
inner join DWH_VW.Volados.DimRutaOW R on F.iID_RutaOW = R.iID_RutaOW
where datepart(year, S.dFec_Vuelo_Real) = 2020
  and datepart(month, S.dFec_Vuelo_Real) = 8
group by T.iNum_Dia, r.cCod_RutaOW with rollup
order by 1
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

***Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.***

Comment: Eso viene de una vista?, justo lo único importante es ver el código de esa vista

Comment: No es una vista

Comment: El error viene dado que en tu nuevo agrupado algún campo en las divisiones tiene un 0, si ejecutas tu consulta sin los campos YIELD, LF,PRASK,"AVERAGE FARE", que segun veo son los que te pueden dar problema y ya viene calculados, que resultados te arroja

Comment: Si me arroja resultados de las demás columnas

Comment: Alguno de los que usas en las divisiónes te da 0

Answer (score 0):

El error indica claramente que está ocurriendo una división por cero.

La explicación de por qué aparece el error al agregar el nuevo campo y agrupar por él, es que en alguna de las columnas, resulta que dentro del nuevo agrupamiento, el divisor es cero.

Las columnas candidatas son:

- `YIELD`
- `LF`
- `PRASK`
- `AVERAGE FARE`

La técnica que prefiero para evitar este error es convertir la expresión a `NULL` en caso que el divisor sea cero. Esto es técnicamente correcto, ya que `NULL` significa literalmente: **No definido** o desconocido.  Y el resultado de una división por cero es **no definido**.

Para lograrlo, me valgo de la función [`NullIf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql), que devuelve `Null` si la expresión recibida como primer parámetro es igual al segundo, o el resultado de dicha expresión en cualquier otro caso. Entonces, sustituyendo expresiones como esta:

```
select Valor1 / Valor2
```

Por:

```
select Valor1 / NullIf(Valor2, 0)
```

Y dado que `x/null` = `null`, elimino los errores de división por cero y obtengo `NULL` en dichas columnas, en tu caso, la columna `YIELD` quedaría así:

```
, sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) * 100 / NullIf(sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)), 0) YIELD
```

Otra posible solución es valerse de una sentencia `case` para retornar algún otro valor (por ejemplo cero, lo cual me parece incorrecto, pero es habitual en requerimientos). En este caso, realizamos la división solo si estamos seguros que el denominador no es cero, la idea es sustituir expresiones como esta:

```
select Valor1 / Valor2
```

Por expresiones así:

```
select case Valor2
         when 0 then 0
         else Valor1 / Valor2
       end
```

O así:

```
select case 
         when Valor2 <> 0 then Valor1 / Valor2
         else 0
       end
```

En este caso, la columna `yield` quedaría así:

```
, case
    when sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) <> 0 then
      sum(S.yInd_SumTotal_MXP) * 100 / sum(S.iNum_PaxRevenue * iif(S.iInd_Distancia_Prev = 0, S.iInd_Distancia_Real, S.iInd_Distancia_Prev)) 
    else 0
  end YIELD
```

Elige uno de los dos métodos y aplicalo a las columnas que menciono al inicio de mi respuesta para solucionar el problema.