# Error dividir por cero

Tags: sql, sql-server

Al tratar de actualizar un campo en sql server  me sale el siguiente mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el el update que trato de hacer como ven en el proc mando pesocava pero al actualizar sale ese mensaje y al actualizarlo directamente desde la tabla en sql server también sale igual

```
ALTER proc SAP_EditarLotes
@IdAnimal nvarchar (100),
@Peso decimal (18,2),
@PesoCava decimal (18,2)
as
update  tblmvto_lotes set peso=@Peso, pesocava=@PesoCava where animal=@IdAnimal
go
```

No tengo ni la mas mínima idea de por que sale esto esta es la estructura de la tabla el campo es pesocava el cuarto campo

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblmvto_lotes](
    [codlote] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [animal] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [peso] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [pesocava] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [fechacava] [datetime] NULL,
    [codtipo] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [id] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [sexo] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [rendimiento] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [ciclan] [bit] NULL,
    [observaciones] [char](200) NULL,
    [pesociclan] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [LLAVESAP] [char](20) NULL,
    [DCTOSAP] [char](20) NULL,
    [FECHASAP] [datetime] NULL,
    [marcaventa] [int] NULL,
    [CantInv] [int] NULL,
    [TipoCanal] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [FechaEnvioSacrio] [datetime] NULL,
    [granja] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [remision] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [pesopie] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [pesocaliente] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [pesofrio] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [valorkilopie] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [valorkilocaliente] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [valorkilofrio] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [valorcanalpie] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [valorcanalcaliente] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [valorcanalfrio] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [NumeroOrejas] [int] NULL,
    [NumeroTesticulos] [int] NULL,
    [Muesca] [bit] NULL,
    [CantEtiquetasContador] [int] NULL,
    [M] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [Sin] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [identificador] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_mvtolotes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [codlote] ASC,
    [animal] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 70, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblmvto_lotes_M]  DEFAULT (N'N') FOR [M]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] ADD  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Sin]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblmvto_lotes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblmvto_lotes_tbllotes] FOREIGN KEY([codlote])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tbllotes] ([codlote])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblmvto_lotes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblmvto_lotes_tbllotes]
GO
```

Este es el triggers que dispara este error

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_CosteoInventarioCanalesUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[tblmvto_lotes]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (UPDATE(peso))
    BEGIN
        SELECT I.codlote, I.animal, I.peso, MVLO.pesopie, MVLO.pesocaliente, MVLO.pesofrio, MVLO.valorkilopie, MVLO.valorkilocaliente, MVLO.valorcanalpie, MVLO.valorcanalcaliente
        INTO #AnimalesCaliente
        FROM inserted AS I
        JOIN tblmvto_lotes AS MVLO
        ON I.codlote = MVLO.codlote
        AND I.animal = MVLO.animal

        UPDATE #AnimalesCaliente
        SET valorkilocaliente = valorcanalpie / peso

        UPDATE #AnimalesCaliente
        SET valorcanalcaliente = peso * valorkilocaliente

        UPDATE #AnimalesCaliente
        SET pesocaliente = peso

        UPDATE MVLO
        SET MVLO.valorkilocaliente = AN.valorkilocaliente, 
            MVLO.valorcanalcaliente = AN.valorcanalcaliente,
            MVLO.pesocaliente = AN.pesocaliente
        FROM tblmvto_lotes AS MVLO
        JOIN #AnimalesCaliente AS AN
        ON MVLO.codlote = AN.codlote
        AND MVLO.animal = AN.animal

        DROP TABLE #AnimalesCaliente
    END

    IF (UPDATE(pesocava))
    BEGIN
        SELECT I.codlote, I.animal, I.pesocava, MVLO.pesopie, MVLO.pesofrio, MVLO.valorkilopie, MVLO.valorkilofrio, MVLO.valorcanalpie, MVLO.valorcanalfrio
        INTO #AnimalesFrio
        FROM inserted AS I
        JOIN tblmvto_lotes AS MVLO
        ON I.codlote = MVLO.codlote
        AND I.animal = MVLO.animal

        UPDATE #AnimalesFrio
        SET valorkilofrio = valorcanalpie / pesocava

        UPDATE #AnimalesFrio
        SET valorcanalfrio = pesocava * valorkilofrio

        UPDATE #AnimalesFrio
        SET pesofrio = pesocava

        UPDATE MVLO
        SET MVLO.valorkilofrio = AN.valorkilofrio, 
            MVLO.valorcanalfrio = AN.valorcanalfrio,
            MVLO.pesofrio = AN.pesofrio
        FROM tblmvto_lotes AS MVLO
        JOIN #AnimalesFrio AS AN
        ON MVLO.codlote = AN.codlote
        AND MVLO.animal = AN.animal

        DROP TABLE #AnimalesFrio
    END
END
```

Comment: En tu tabla no se ve que tengas campos calculados, podrías revisar si tiene triggers, seguramente tienen alguno y ahí es donde se genera el error.

Comment: Encontré el trigger que dispara ese mensaje

Comment: Ese error te da pq estas dividiendo un número con 0, revisando tu código veo que tienes la división valorcanalpie /pesocava, revisa esto y valida que peso cava no puede ser 0, mira a ver si tienes más divisiones

Comment: Aquí te dejo la respuesta, espero te funcione, https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/391511/150924

Comment: SET valorkilofrio = valorcanalpie / NullIf(pesocava,0) esta fue la solución  muchas gracias NullIf

Answer (score 0):

Mira que las variables que pasa a través de las arrobas no estén vacías, ya que por defecto una variable de tipo int o que use números, si están vacías, las rellena automáticamente con un 0...y obviamente, nada se puede dividir entre 0